# How to upgrade node legacy (ubuntu)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

My node version is

> `6.x.x` (node -v)

but `nodejs -v` returns 0.10.x .

How to upgrade the nodejs version , and what is the difference in node and nodejs ?

Comment: yes , i am using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I highly recommend taking a look at Node Version Manager (nvm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo bash -

sudo apt-get install nodejs

> ```
> nodejs -v
> v7.10.0
> ```